# Windows Workflow Foundation 4.0 connector

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I'm trying to create a custom activity with multiple connectors using WWF 4.0.
Could you tell me how to declare connectors at activity level and register to click event on a flowswitch connector?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be going with approach described
[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/1d397575-8d6a-4208-a947-7e28da1a8a29)